# Evaluating a minimum mean square error explicitly

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation, information-theory, decision-theory

I have a minimum mean squared error (MMSE) expression that I would like to evaluate explicitly:
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X+\mathbb{E}[X|CX+G])^2],
$$
where:

- $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\nu)$ where $\nu$ is some fixed constant and $G\sim N(0,1)$;
- $X$ and $G$ are independent of each other;
- $C$ is just some fixed constant (non-random).

**Question:** Is it possible to evaluate the MMSE expression explicitly? Otherwise, how far can we go? I don't mind the integrations. Thanks.

**Remark:** This [paper](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Eyw562/reprints/mmse_analyticity.pdf) looks at what the form would take if $X$ is Gaussian.